# How to get the private key from a jail broken iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I want to replicate what an `iOS` device does while OTA (Over the air) installation of profiles. I need this functionality to do automated testing of OTA  server code.

As part of OTA process, `iOS` signs device attributes with built-in device certificate/private key and the server checks the signature. So, my testing harness should do the same.

How can I get a built-in certificate/private key from my jailbroken device to use it in my testing code?

Comment: No help should be given for things that could be used for extreme mischief. Private keys must never, ever leave a device.

Comment: I want to use my own device's private key. Its for automating some steps which could only be perfomed by connecting to real iphone. I'm an automation engineer not a hacker or an iphone developer.

Comment: @creker: I updated the questions to explain what exactly is signed.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: I personally know this automated engineer.